# How can I pass data from view to controller using ajax?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

**Code in view:**

```
function DeleteSelected() {
    var data = "ID=";
    $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('name') == "IDS[]") {
            if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
                data += $(this).val();
                data += ":";
            }
        }
    });
    alert(data.toString());
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Color/DeleteAll',
        type: "POST",
        data: "1,2",
        dataType: "json",
       // contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            location.reload();
        },
        error: function () {
            location.reload();
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}
```

**Code in Controller**

```
public string DeleteAll(string data)
{
    gen_ColorModel a = new Models.EDUERPGeneral.gen_ColorModel();
    a.Gen_ColorFactory.Delete(a.Gen_Color);
    string ids = data;
    string[] allIDs = ids.Split(':');
    // rest of the code
    return "";
}
```

In Controller data is null that should not be null

Comment: Pass an array - `data: { id : [ 1, 2 ] },` and add the `traditional: true,` ajax option, then make the parameter `public ActinResult DeleteAll(IEnumerable<int> ids)`

Comment: Your data to pass should really be in JSON format. So use name/value pairs.

Comment: thanks Stephen using array worked for me :)

Comment: And delete your `location.reload();` - the whole point of making an ajax call is to stay on the same page! (doing that is pointless) - return a `JsonResult` indicating success or otherwise, and if successful, remove the items from the DOM assuming that's what your trying to do

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass your data from ajax call using param data like as following.

```
$('#Link').click(function () {      
$.ajax({
    url: http://localhost/Account/Process,
    type: 'GET',
    data: { 
            id: "@ViewBag.MyUser.ID",
            name: "@ViewBag.MyUser.Name" 
          },
    success: function () {
    },
    error: function () {                
    }
});
```

and Get that data on Controller as following.

```
public ActionResult Process(int id, string name)
{
   //Do something
}
```

Hope this will help you.
thanks

Comment: What does this have to to with OP's question (which is about passing an array of values!)

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Controller/method";
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: {
        variable1: value1,
        variable2: value2,
        variable3: value3,
    }
    success: function(rs) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! 
Please, read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and try to provide some explanation for the code you are pasting here.
Thanks!